# readcsv when text has commas

Tags: r, csv

I'm trying to read.csv thousands of csv files into R but am into a lot of trouble when a my text has commas.

My csv file has 16 columns with headers. Some of the text in column 1 has commas. Column 2 is a string, and Column 3 is always a number.

For instance an entry in column 1 is:
"I do not know Robert, Kim, or Douglas"- Marcus. A. Ten, Inc President

When I try to

```
df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(paste(CSVpath, fileNames, sep=""), read.csv, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=TRUE, row.names=NULL))
```

I get a df with more than 16 columns and the above text is split into 4 columns:

```
V1                        V2      V3                               V4
"I do not know Robert     Kim     or Douglas" - Marcus. A. Ten     Inc President
```

when I need it all in one column as:

```
V1
"I do not know Robert, Kim, or Douglas"- Marcus. A. Ten, Inc President
```

Comment: well, you set the separator to nothing so you got what you asked for. this is a pretty malformed CSV. you should really paste the first few lines of the raw CSV to see if folks can help you find a pattern you can split on.

Comment: The general way go get a separator ignored is by quoting it, but you've already got quotes being used another way. How was the CSV written? Is the separator character actually a comma? What is the quote character? If everything else fails, you can default to `readLines`, but it won't be much fun.

Comment: This is status data from user's timelines. So the first column is the text of the tweet then the next column says whether or not the tweet was retreeted and so has the value of TRUE or FALSE. The third column is an integer 0 or higher saying how many times it was retweeted. So what's throwing everything off is when a tweet has quotes and commas. The csv can be imported into SQL using a text qualifier " but to get it into R is where I'm stuck.

Comment: I gotta say I'm *really* curious which SQL interpreter is correctly inferring which commas are real and which are not. Perhaps this will be partly answered by seeing some real data.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you have control over the data output format, I strongly urge you to either (a) correctly quote the fields, or (b) use another character as a delimiter (e.g., tab, pipe "|"). This is the ideal solution, as it will certainly speed up future processing and "fix the glitch", so to speak.

Lacking that, you can try to programmatically fix all rows. Assuming that only the first column is problematic (i.e., all of the other columns are perfectly defined), then *on a line-by-line basis*, change the true-separators to a different delimiter (e.g., pipe or tab).

For this example, I have 4 columns delimited with a comma, and I'm going to change the legitimate separators to a pipe.

1. Some data and magic constants:

   ```
   txt <- '"I do not know Robert, Kim, or Douglas" - Marcus. A. Ten, Inc President,TRUE,0,14
   "Something, else",FALSE,1,15
   "Something correct",TRUE,2,22
   Something else,FALSE,3,33'
   nColumns <- 4 # known a priori
   oldsep <- ","
   newsep <- "|"
   ```

   In your case, you'll read in the data:

   ```
   txt <- readLines("path/to/malformed.csv")
   nColumns <- 16
   ```
2. Do a manual (text-based, not parsing for data types) separation:

   ```
   splits <- strsplit(readLines(textConnection(txt)), oldsep)
   ```

   Realize that this reads, for example, the false fields as the verbatim characters `"FALSE"`, not as a boolean data type. This *might* be avoided if we take on the magic type-detection done by `read.csv` and cousins, but why?
3. *Per line*: first ignore the last `nColumns-1` fields, take the first fields and recombine them with the old separator, resulting in a single field (with commas); now combine this with the remaining `nColumns-1` fields and combine these with the new separator. (BTW: making sure we deal with quoting double-quotes correctly, too.)

   ```
   txt2 <- sapply(splits, function(vec) {
     n <- length(vec)
     if (n < nColumns) return(paste(vec, collapse = newsep))
     vec1 <- paste(vec[1:(n - nColumns + 1)], collapse = oldsep)
     vec1 <- sprintf('"%s"', gsub('"', '""', vec1))
     paste(c(vec1,
             vec[(n - nColumns + 2):n]), collapse = newsep)
   })
   txt2[1]
   # [1] "\"\"\"I do not know Robert, Kim, or Douglas\"\" - Marcus. A. Ten, Inc President\"|TRUE|0|14"
   ```

   (The `sprintf` line may not be necessary if the original file has correct quoting of double-quotes ... but then again, if it had correct quoting, we wouldn't be having this problem in the first place.)
4. Now, either absorb the data directly into a data.frame:

   ```
   read.csv(textConnection(txt2), header = FALSE, sep = newsep)
   #                                                                        V1    V2 V3 V4
   # 1 "I do not know Robert, Kim, or Douglas" - Marcus. A. Ten, Inc President  TRUE  0 14
   # 2                                                       "Something, else" FALSE  1 15
   # 3                                                     "Something correct"  TRUE  2 22
   # 4                                                          Something else FALSE  3 33
   ```

   or write these back to a file (good if you want to deal with these files elsewhere), adding `con = "path/to/filename` as appropriate:

   ```
   writeLines(txt2)
   # """I do not know Robert, Kim, or Douglas"" - Marcus. A. Ten, Inc President"|TRUE|0|14
   # """Something, else"""|FALSE|1|15
   # """Something correct"""|TRUE|2|22
   # "Something else"|FALSE|3|33
   ```

   (Two notable changes: the *correct* comma-delimiters are now pipes, and all other commas are still commas; and there is correct quoting around the double-quotes. Yes, an escaped double-quote is just two double-quotes. That's what R expects if there are quotes within a field.)

NB: though this seems to work with my fabricated data (and I hope it works with yours), you do not hear of people touting R's speed and efficiency in doing text mangling in this fashion. There are ***certainly*** better ways to do this, perhaps using python, awk, or sed. There are possibly faster ways to do this in R.